# Why does neural net optimizer change from SGD to Adam lead to massive decrease in accuracies?

Tags: neural-network, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm training a covnet on ~10,000 images and have noticed that switching the optimizer from `opt = SGD()` to `opt = 'adam'` leads to massive reduction in accuracies, keeping all else params equal. With SGD(), I get to about 80% accuracy (with gradual increases after each epoch). With Adam, I'm stuck at 22.25% validation accuracies at every epoch.

**I want to understand what the likely cause for this is.**

Parameters

```
dropout_prob = 0.2
activation_function = 'relu'
loss_function = 'categorical_crossentropy'
batch_size = 32
epoch_count = 20
num_classes = 3
```

Model

```
 model = Sequential()
        model.add(Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=(3, 3), input_shape=inp_shape))
        model.add(Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3, 3)))
        model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
        model.add(Dropout(rate=dropout_prob))
        model.add(Flatten())
        model.add(Dense(128, activation=activation_function))
        model.add(Dropout(rate=dropout_prob))
        model.add(Dense(64, activation=activation_function))
        model.add(Dropout(rate=dropout_prob))
        model.add(Dense(32, activation=activation_function))
        model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))
        model.summary()
        model.compile(loss=loss_function, optimizer=opt, metrics=['accuracy'])
        history = model.fit(x_train, y_train_cat, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epoch_count,
                            verbose=verbose_level,
                            validation_data=(x_test, y_test_cat))
```

Comment: What is `opt` ?

Comment: I am curios, did my answer solve your question?

Answer (score 3):

Different optimizers might require different optimization hyper parameters to converge.
Try replacing `opt='adam'` (which uses the default learning rate) with

```
opt = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=learning_rate)
```

and instead of using the default value of `learning_rate`, choose its value using [cross-validation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_(statistics)).

As a rule of thumb, usually the learning rate would be somewhere between 1e-6..0.1. You can try with the following values for the learning rate: `[1e-6, 3e-6, 1e-5, 3e-5, 1e-4, ..., 1e-1]`

Answer (score 1):

A drawback of SGD-based optimizers is that they rely upon scalar and uniform learning of gradients in all the directions (i.e., for all the parameters for which gradient is to be updated). In contrast, adaptive learning strategies such as Adam diagonally scale the gradient based upon estimates of the function’s curvature. Instead of maintaining a learning rate that is shared amongst multiple parameters, Adam uses a vector of learning rates, one for each parameter and adapts those as the training progresses. It is this non-uniform scaling of the gradients that results in the lag of generalization capabilites of Adam, and probably in your case, the massive decrease in accuracies.

As mentioned in [Improving Generalization Performance by Switching from Adam to SGD](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1712.07628.pdf):

> Despite superior training outcomes, adaptive optimization methods such
>   as Adam, Adagrad or RMSprop have been found to generalize poorly
>   compared to Stochastic gradient descent (SGD). These methods tend to
>   perform well in the initial portion of training but are outperformed
>   by SGD at later stages of training.

In order to combine the best of both the optimizers, they introduce a switching technique from Adam to SGD by taking care of: (a) the switchover point, i.e. how long to train the model with Adam before switching to SGD. As a thumb rule, the paper points at switiching after at least 10 epochs. (b) the learning rate to be used for SGD after the switch: determined by the momentum parameter `beta_1` of Adam.

A good explanation can be found [here](https://github.com/kweonwooj/papers/issues/76).